# Restore Operation in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, restore, database-restore

I want to restore database from backup[.bak] file over an existing database.
  Backup file is a full database backup.
  What is more efficient? Restoring to a new database OR Overwriting an existing database?

Answer (score 0):

Over the top will be better. The storage engine will need to zero-fill your files (well... at least the log file if you've set configured instant file initialization) on the disk. If the files are big, that's a lot of 0's to write. If you overwrite, the server knows that the space on the disk isn't filled with junk and doesn't have to do as much work.